# Product of increasing functions is integrable in two dimensions

Tags: real-analysis

> We say $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is **increasing** if $f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$ whenever $x_1<x_2$. If $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are increasing and non-negative, show that the function $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ is integrable over $[0,1]^2$.

I'm using the Darboux definition of integration, so I want to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $Q$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$. Equivalently, there exists a partition $P$ of $Q$ such that $$\left|\sum_Rv(R)(M_R(f)-m_R(f))\right|<\epsilon,$$ where $M_R(f)$ is the supremum of the values of $f$ inside the rectangle $R$, and $m_R(f)$ is the corresponding value for infimum. (Here, $R$ ranges over all subrectangles formed by the partition $P$.)

Toward that end, I tried to take the partition $P$ to be $[0,\dfrac1n,\dfrac2n,\ldots,1]\times[0,\dfrac1n,\dfrac2n,\ldots,1]$. Since the function $h(x,y)$ is increasing in $x$ and $y$, the maximum of any square is attained at the top-right corner, and the minimum at the bottom-left corner. Therefore, $\left|\sum_Rv(R)(M_R(f)-m_R(f))\right|$ is equal to $$\dfrac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\dfrac in)g(1)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(1)g(\dfrac in)-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\dfrac in)g(0)-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(0)g(\dfrac in)\right)$$

I'm not sure if this is the right partition to take. Does this sum approach $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Actually such a function is usually called _nondecreasing_, and IMHO that is a better, more accurate, and more descriptive term.

Comment: It could not be said that $M_i (h) = M_i (f) M_i (g)$?

Comment: How did you get the expansion in the last part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Given the cancellations that you have already performed, along with $f(x)\leq f(1)$ and $g(y)\leq g(1)$ for all $x,y\in[0,1]$, the triangle inequality implies
$$
\left\lvert\sum_R v(R)(M_R(f)-m_R(f))\right\rvert\leq\frac{4nf(1)g(1)}{n^2}.
$$

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about bounding every term with $f(1)$ and $g(1)$. But that works because the number of terms is linear in $n$. Thanks, Nicholas!

Comment: However, we do not know that $f$ and $g$ are bounded on $I$, so how can you show that that bound can be made less than $\epsilon$ with an appropriate $n$ ?

Comment: Because $f(1)$ and $g(1)$ are just fixed numbers -- they don't depend on $n$.  So, when you cancel an $n$ from the numerator and denominator, you're left with some number over $n$... and it is pretty easy to make that small by making $n$ large.

Comment: @NickPeterson Ok, thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$\sum_{R} M_R(f)v(R)=\sum_{1\leq i\leq n\\1\leq j\leq n}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{j}{n})\frac{1}{n^2}\leq\sum_{0\leq i\leq n\\0\leq j\leq n}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{j}{n})\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
$$\sum_{R} m_R(f)v(R)=\sum_{0\leq i\leq n-1\\0\leq j\leq n-1}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{j}{n})\frac{1}{n^2}.$$

$$\sum_{R} M_R(f)v(R)-\sum_{R} m_R(f)v(R)\leq\sum_{0\leq i\leq n\\0\leq j\leq n}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{j}{n})\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{0\leq i\leq n-1\\0\leq j\leq n-1}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{j}{n})\frac{1}{n^2}\\=\frac{1}{n^2}(f(\frac{0}{n})g(\frac{n}{n})+f(\frac{1}{n})g(\frac{n}{n})+\dots+f(\frac{n}{n})g(\frac{n}{n})+f(\frac{n}{n})g(\frac{n-1}{n})+\dots+f(\frac{n}{n})g(\frac{0}{n}))\leq\frac{1}{n^2}(2n+1)f(1)g(1)\to 0(n\to\infty).$$