# If $f,g: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R} $ are increasing and non-negative functions, show that the function $h(x, y) = f(x)g(y)$ is integrable over $[0, 1]^2$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* at page 90 question 4, it is asked that

> We say $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is increing if $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$
>   whenever $x_1<x_2$. If $f, g : (0, 1] \to \mathbb{R} $ are increing
>   and non-negative, show that the function $h(x, y) = f(x)g(y)$ is
>   integrable over $[0, 1]^2$.

and the same question has been asked in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479924/product-of-increasing-functions-is-integrable-in-two-dimensions); however, how do we know the values $f(1)$ and $g(1)$ are finite ? I mean there is nothing that assumes the functions are bounded in the statement of the question as far as I can see.

Comment: What else than finite could they be? Every element of $\Bbb R$ is finite, isn't it?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier see my comments to the given answer.

Comment: Your suggestions don't have domain $[0,1]$ as required.

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks for the correction John, I did not noticed.

Comment: The conclusion makes no sense - since $h(x,y)$ is a function of two variables it  cant be integrable on $[0,1]$. What does the problem actually ask?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Perhaps a typo. The integration should be on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f, g : (0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, hence $f((0,1]) \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $g((0,1]) \subseteq \mathbb R$ , therefore $f(1),g(1) \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: the domain is $I = [0,1]$, and not $(0,1]$.

Comment: and what about $f(x) = 1/x$ ? isn't codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R} $ ?

Comment: or $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas the domain of $f(x)$ is $(0,1]$, so $f(1)$ is a real number (it is the definition of function).

Comment: $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$ is not defined at $x=1$. @onurcanbektas

Comment: @JohnMa and Fred, then why do we have a concept called "bounded function" then ? After all, for $f(x) = 1/x$, where $f: (0,1]$, the value of $f$ for any $x$ in the domain has some value in $\mathbb{R}$ (hence not $\infty$).

Comment: @JohnMa and Fred, Ok I have understood what I'm missing. Thanks for the help.